# Summing only number properties of object

Tags: javascript, oop

I have created a  method that returns multiple mappedObjecst which contain an id and the hours logged daily.

This is the code that returns the mapping:

```
 return Object.keys(tableData).map(key => {
      const mappedObject = {
        id: key
      };
      tableData[key].forEach(weekday => {
          mappedObject[weekday.day] = Math.round( (weekday.spent / 3600) * 10) / 10;
      });
      return mappedObject;
    });
```

here are the returned mappedObjects:

```
{id: "c94.33", MON: 8, WED: 3.2, FRI: 5.3}
{id: "c.005.001", THU: 8}
{id: "unspecified", TUE: 8, WED: 4.8, FRI: 2.7}
```

How do I make subsums of the hours under each id?

For example:

c94.33 : 16.5

c.005.001: 8

unspecified: 15.5

My idea and what I tried:
-create an array and .push into the array mappedObject's values.

```
    return Object.keys(tableData).map(key => {
      const mappedObject = {
        id: key
      };
      tableData[key].forEach(weekday => {
          mappedObject[weekday.day] = Math.round( (weekday.spent / 3600) * 10) / 10;
          this.totalHoursPerid.push(_.sum(_.values(mappedObject)));
          console.log(this.totalHoursPerid);
      });
      return mappedObject;
    });
  }
```

this doesnt work because the id key has a string value(at least thats what i think).

As requested in the comments ,this is the tableData thats being parsed:

```
{c94.33:
 [{day: "MON", spent: 28800},
  {day: "WED", spent: 11400},
  {day: "FRI", spent: 19200}],
c.005.001: 
 [{day: "THU", spent: 28800}],
unspecified:
 [{day: "TUE", spent: 28800},
  {day: "WED", spent: 17400},
  {day: "FRI", spent: 9600}]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the original sample input too?

Comment: Can you show the tableData that you input too ?

Comment: added inside the post

Comment: the spent field is time in secods and i converted it in hours + minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce`. Extract the `id` and then you can apply `Object.values` to get values of other properties.

```js
const input = [
    {id: "c94.33", MON: 8, WED: 3.2, FRI: 5.3}, 
    {id: "c.005.001", THU: 8}, 
    {id: "unspecified", TUE: 8, WED: 4.8, FRI: 2.7}
];

const output = input.reduce((accu, {id, ...rest}) => {
    accu[id] = Object.values(rest).reduce((accu, val) => accu + val, 0);
    return accu;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

You can also use `map`,

```js
const input = [
    {id: "c94.33", MON: 8, WED: 3.2, FRI: 5.3}, 
    {id: "c.005.001", THU: 8}, 
    {id: "unspecified", TUE: 8, WED: 4.8, FRI: 2.7}
];

const output = input.map(({id, ...rest}) => ({[id]: Object.values(rest).reduce((accu, val) => accu + val, 0)}));
console.log(output);
```

```js
const tableData = {
    "c94.33": [
        {day: "MON", spent: 28800},
        {day: "WED", spent: 11400},
        {day: "FRI", spent: 19200}
    ],
    "c.005.001": [
        {day: "THU", spent: 28800}
    ],
   "unspecified":[
       {day: "TUE", spent: 28800},
       {day: "WED", spent: 17400},
       {day: "FRI", spent: 9600}
    ]
}

const output = Object.entries(tableData).map(([key, val]) => {
    const sum = val.reduce((accu, {spent}) => {
        accu = accu + Math.round( (spent / 3600) * 10) / 10;
        return accu;
    }, 0)
    return ({[key]: sum})
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I tried your snippet and it shows this error: "Property 'reduce' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }'" and this: "Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and '{}'" when you try to add the value (at the second reduce)

Comment: the "return mappedObject" in my code returns a single object,not an array of objects.

Comment: Can you please add your object? `reduce` and `map` works on array. It would be great if you can add your input object.

Comment: do you mean tableData ?Ive added it to the post

Answer (score 2):

```js
let tableData = {"c94.33":
    [{day: "MON", spent: 28800},
     {day: "WED", spent: 11400},
     {day: "FRI", spent: 19200}],
   "c.005.001": 
    [{day: "THU", spent: 28800}],
   "unspecified":
    [{day: "TUE", spent: 28800},
     {day: "WED", spent: 17400},
     {day: "FRI", spent: 9600}]
   }


console.log( Object.keys(tableData).map(key => {
    const mappedObject = {};
      
    var spenttime = 0
    tableData[key].forEach(weekday => {
        spenttime  += Math.round( (weekday.spent / 3600) * 10) / 10;
    });

    mappedObject[key] = spenttime
    return mappedObject;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine it all up and work out the sums for the days as you're creating the new output:

```js
const tableData = {"c94.33":[{"day":"MON","spent":28800},{"day":"WED","spent":11400},{"day":"FRI","spent":19200}],"c.005.001":[{"day":"THU","spent":28800}],"unspecified":[{"day":"TUE","spent":28800},{"day":"WED","spent":17400},{"day":"FRI","spent":9600}]};

const calc = spent => Math.round((spent / 3600) * 10) / 10;

// Iterate over the object entries
const out = Object.entries(tableData).reduce((acc, [key, dayArr]) => {

  // `map` over the day array to calculate the spend
  const days = dayArr.map(({ day, spent }) => ({ [day]: calc(spent) }));

  // Use that array to calculate the sum
  const spent = days.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + Object.values(obj)[0], 0);

  // Create and return a new object
  acc[key] = { days, spent };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```